# How can I hide signup/ signin(login) link/button after user login.I am using httpSession

Tags: java, authentication, logout, httpsession

I would like to check if session not equals to null,then some button or link will be hidden.Or any other better way to do that?
This is my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Object signIn(HttpSession session) {

    MemberSignIn signIn = new MemberSignIn();
    signIn.setLoginId((String) session.getAttribute("loginId"));

    return new ModelAndView("member/signin").addObject("signIn", signIn);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/signin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object signIn(@ModelAttribute MemberSignIn memberSignIn, HttpSession session, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    try {
        Session s = memberService.signIn(memberSignIn);
        session.setAttribute("loginId", memberSignIn.getLoginId());
        session.setAttribute("token", s.getToken());
        session.setAttribute("memberId", s.getMemberId());

        MemberDetail detail = memberService.detail(s.getMemberId());
        session.setAttribute("name", detail.getName());

        return "redirect:/index";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return new ModelAndView("member/signin")
                .addObject("signIn", memberSignIn)
                .addObject("error", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<li><a href="/signin" class="button special">Sign In</a></li>
            <li><a href="/signup" class="button special">Sign Up</a></li>
```

Comment: Using a filter here would be good design. Instead of just checking this in the controller, use a filter as an interceptor for each request and check the session attribute `loginId` there. If it exists, then directly by pass the sign in page and to the page the user has requested.

Comment: as anonymous and authorized user will share a same page,i just wanted to hide/add some of the navigation bar.Is it possible too to used the filter?

Comment: Yes. That is what the filter is for ! So if a user hits any of your site pages, the filter will first intercept the request, and in the  'doFilter' method you can check for session attribute. Based on the session attribute being present or not, you can set a flag as an attribute in the session and use this flag everywhere in your site. You can also modify your `web.xml` to only hit the filter on certain types of URL requests. All customizable !